# Buffer size for getdents64 to finish in one go

Tags: c, linux, directory, system-calls

On Linux, is it possible to get the buffer size required for `getdents64` to get all the entries in one go (assuming no modifications to the directory after the size is obtained)?

I tried the value from `fstat(dirfd,&stb); stb.st_size` but it appears unnecessarily too large? What is the value that `stat::st_size` holds for directories?

Comment: Are you calling `fstat(dirfd,&stb);` on a directory that has had a lot of members deleted from it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle It tried it on a bunch of directories like /, /tmp, /etc/, /home, so in short, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, no, there is no way to do this, especially not in a manner that works for arbitrary filesystems. The representation of directories is defined by the underlying filesystem, and the same seems to be true of `st_size`. Certainly there is no way to get the right value for FUSE or 9p or other remote/virtual filesystems.

Why do you want to do this? I don't think it's useful. Once you get beyond a few kB per call, the overhead of the syscalls will be dominated by the actual work done. If you really care you can wrap the `getdents64` syscall with a function that keeps resizing the buffer and calling it until EOF is reached. Or you could just use the portable `opendir`/`readdir` interfaces which perform appropriate buffering for you.